# Receive an undefined reference error when make teleop_nao_ni

Tags: urdf, ros-electric, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When trying to rosmake the nao_openni package I receive the following error:

Linking CXX executable ../bin/teleop_nao_ni

/opt/ros/electric/stacks/robot_model/urdf/lib/liburdf.so: error: undefined reference to 'operator<<(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits >&, TiXmlNode const&)'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

This error only occurs on making the teleop_nao_ni executable. Anyone have any suggestions on what I can do to fix the liburdf.so error?

Note: All the dependencies for the package compile fine, the paths are correct (ros_package_path, pythonpath, pythonhome, ros_workspace) and the object file compiles so there shouldn't be an error in the cpp file.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37399/receive-an-undefined-reference-error-when-make-teleop_nao_ni/) by [Curious Joe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2724/curious-joe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I had the same problem with the 'planning_models' package in 'armnavigation' stack. You need to edit manifest.xml of the urdf package and append '-ltinyxml' to the 'cpp cflags' line.
The resulting line looks like:

```
<cpp cflags="-I${prefix}/include" lflags="-Wl,-rpath,${prefix}/lib -L${prefix}/lib -lurdf -ltinyxml"/>
```

---

Originally posted by [Jürgen Kunz](https://answers.ros.org/users/2913/j%C3%BCrgen-kunz/) with karma: 36 on 2012-07-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-07-24**:
I would recommend creating ticket for this fix in the bug tracker for URDF.